# What does it mean when an integral contains dx'?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to use the following mathematical model to model some Physical properties of materials. Alpha and Beta are constants but I have a question about the integration. Here is the equation:

[Equation from McIntyre (1966) that I am trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iIIN.png)

My question is: there is a dx' (and dx'') in the integrals. Am I supposed to evaluate this integral any differently than normal? Additionally, there is an x' bound. How would this be handled?

Comment: The "inner" integral produces a function of $x'$ that is in turn integrated to produce $M(x)$ that is a function of $x$

Comment: $$\int_x^w(\alpha-\beta)\,\mathrm dx'=(\alpha-\beta)x'\bigg|_{x'=x}^{x'=w}=(\alpha-\beta)(w-x)$$

Comment: Well, many Calculus student don't really understand the concept of "dummy variables'.

Comment: This isn't a silly question, and it's no wonder you're confused. The choice of variable is poor, since we use primes to indicate derivatives.

Comment: that is, instead of $x', dx', x'', dx''$ the author might have made a better choice to use $y,dy,z,dz$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as there is nothing else relating to $x$ present in each of the integrals, you can treat $x'$ as a variable in its own right, that is to say:
$$\int dx'=x'+C$$
if there were an expression of $x$ present it would be much more difficult although $x$ could also represent a function i.e. $x=x(t)$ which would give you:
$$dx'=d\left[\frac{dx}{dt}\right]=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}dt$$